# Error Code Object Required for Autofilter

Tags: excel, vba, object, range, type-mismatch

Currently I am trying to delete all values showing 0 and 0.00 from my column titled "Current Ac". The code is supposed to look for the column header Current Ac select the entire range of data (which can vary) then filter for values 0 and 0.00 within the "Current Ac" column and delete those rows.

As of right now for the following rows of code I have received the respective error messages:

```
x = HQSL.Application.Match("Current Ac", Range("A1", Cells(1, LastCol)), 0)
```

> Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

and

```
.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="0", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="0.00"
```

> Run-time error '424': object required

I have tried to `Dim X As Variant`, and `LastCol` and `LastRow As Long` but I still receive the same error.
I have tried to `Dim` them all as `Variant` as well.

```
Sub FilteredAndDeletedZeros1()

    Dim x As Double
    Dim LastCol As Variant
    Dim LastRow As Variant
    Dim HQSL As Worksheet

Set HQSL = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("HQ SL")

    LastCol = HQSL.Cells(1, HQSL.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    LastRow = HQSL.Cells(HQSL.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    x = HQSL.Application.Match("Current Ac", Range("A1", Cells(1, LastCol)), 0)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With HQSL.Range(Cells(1, x), Cells(LastRow, x)).Value2
        .AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="0", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="0.00"
        .Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
        .AutoFilter
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

ChangeColumnNames1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
With HQSL.Range(Cells(1, x), Cells(LastRow, x)).Value2
```

needs to be changed to

```
With HQSL.Range(HQSL.Cells(1, x), HQSL.Cells(LastRow, x))
```

And this line

```
x = HQSL.Application.Match("Current Ac", Range("A1", Cells(1, LastCol)), 0)
```

needs to be changed into

```
x = Application.Match("Current Ac", HQSL.Range("A1", HQSL.Cells(1, LastCol)), 0)
```

Also you must test if the result of the match is an error or if it was successfull `If Not IsError(x) Then` otherwise you end up in an exception.

In the end it should look something like this:

```
Sub FilteredAndDeletedZeros1()
    Dim HQSL As Worksheet
    Set HQSL = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("HQ SL")

    Dim LastCol As Long
    LastCol = HQSL.Cells(1, HQSL.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = HQSL.Cells(HQSL.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim x As Double
    x = Application.Match("Current Ac", HQSL.Range("A1", HQSL.Cells(1, LastCol)), 0)

    If Not IsError(x) Then  'test if match was successfull
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        With HQSL.Range(HQSL.Cells(1, x), HQSL.Cells(LastRow, x))
            .AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="0", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="0.00"
            .Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
            .AutoFilter
        End With

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Else
        MsgBox "Match failed to find something"
    End If

ChangeColumnNames1

End Sub
```

Comment: @DanielleToval If this solved your question please accept it as answer.

Answer (score -1):

the range function can be used as

```
Range("A1:A100") 'Range of cells
```

or

```
Range(cells(1,1),cells(1,2), ... , Cells(1,100)) 'Individual Cells
```

The first error you are getting is a result of
`Range("A1", Cells(1, LastCol))` You are using a mix of both, that is the type mismatch

The second you are trying to sort the value of two cells

```
HQSL.Range(Cells(1, x), Cells(LastRow, x)).Value2
```

suggest for both you try using

```
Range("A1:" & cells(1,LastCol).address) )
```

Comment: Sorry, but you are not correct! Run `Range("A1", Cells(3, 3)).Select` and you will see that it is a valid operation that does not result in an error. This syntax is totally valid. • While the syntax you suggest `Range(cells(1,1),cells(1,2), ... , Cells(1,100))` throws an exception because `Range` can only accept 2 parameters (You can test it by running `Range(cells(1,1),cells(1,2), Cells(1,100)).Select`. This syntax is not valid and cannot work. • I suggest to read the official [Range object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) documentation.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)               my apologies if I am in Error, I sure that the suggested solution is best though.                  :-)   There is always more to learn.